# iOS - JSONModel with dynamic key

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsonmodel

I am calling a web service which returns dictionary to render the graph. Dictionary structure is

> {"1":0,"2":0,"8":0,"9":2,"10":3,"11":0,"12":0}

The problem is keys are dynamic values like 1,2,3 etc which indicates month. Is it possible to represent this in JsonModel?

Comment: The issue is actually more that Objective-C doesn't allow properties to have names that are numbers (or even anything that begins with a digit). But what's you can definitely manipulate dictionaries derived from JSON without JsonModel, just use `NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` and access keys in the returned `NSDictionary`.

Comment: What is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

See you cant create properties at run time as per response structure. But we can smartly use pre-defined things and achieve this. Do following steps:

Create one model class. So your `MyCustomModel.h` file will look like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyCustomModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * myCustomKey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * myCustomValue;

@end
```

This will be your `MyCustomModel.m` file

```
#import "MyCustomModel.h"

@implementation MyCustomModel
@synthesize myCustomKey, myCustomValue;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    myCustomKey = @"";
    myCustomValue = @"";

    return self;
}
@end
```

Now lets suppose {"1":0,"2":0,"8":0,"9":2,"10":3,"11":0,"12":0} is `NSDictionary` and lets say its name is `dictionaryResponse`

Now do this stuffs:

```
NSArray *responseKeys = [[NSArray alloc]init];
responseKeys = [dictionaryResponse allKeys];
```

So your responseKeys will have all keys of response like ["1","2","8","9","10","11","12",]

Now you can iterate loop and create `NSMutableArray` of model objects as

```
NSMutableArray *arrayMonthList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < responseKeys.count; i++) {
    MyCustomModel *myModelObject = [[MyCustomModel alloc]init];
    myModelObject.myCustomKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
    myModelObject.myCustomValue = [dictionaryResponse valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[responseKeys objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [arrayMonthList addObject:myModelObject];
}
```

Now `arrayMonthList` will consist of objects of type MyCustomModel

So you can use it and parse it. Even you can use it to show on `UITableView`. Following code is written to print values of model properties, you can customise at your expected level.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayMonthList.count; i++) {
        MyCustomModel *myModelObject = [arrayMonthList objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Month is %@ and its value is %@",myModelObject.myCustomKey,myModelObject.myCustomValue);
    }
```